# Verification required when attempting to purchase free app

Tags: ios, ipod-touch, ios-appstore, itunes-store

When I'm trying to install a free app on my iPod, it'll say:

> **Verification Required**
>
> Before you can make purchases, you must tap continue to verify your payment info.

Why do I see this when it's free?
The "None" option is not available.

Answer (score 10):

You need to select that you don't want a payment option on your account.

1. Open the **Settings** app → scroll down to and tap on **iTunes & App Stores**.
2. Tap **View Apple ID** → **Payment Information**.
3. Select **None** as the payment type.

Comment: I did not know this was visible on an idevice, I was going to write the answer about the details in iTunes on the computer but this is way better. +1

Comment: Also make check the address inputted too, I had this problem but it was the case of an incorrect address.